# What happens to an Output Stream/Input Stream object reference after calling close method?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-io

When you call `close()` method on an object reference for OutputStream/InputStream object, will the object reference be pointing to null? or Do we need to explicitly set it to null to make the object memory available for GC?

Comment: Q:  When you call close() method ...  will the object reference be pointing to null?  A: No.  Q: Do we need to explicitly set it to null?  A: No.  That's what differentiates a garbage-collected language (like Java, C# and VB.Net) from a legacy VB6/COM-ActiveX app.  You can read more here: [Java Garbage Collection Basics](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/)

Answer (score 1):

No. `close()` will free some underlying resources and objects, but this object still exists.

Actually, `close()` may not do anything, for example, in `ByteArrayInputStream`

```
/**
 * Closing a <tt>ByteArrayInputStream</tt> has no effect. The methods in
 * this class can be called after the stream has been closed without
 * generating an <tt>IOException</tt>.
 */
public void close() throws IOException {
}
```

you can call `close()` on it, and then still use it like nothing happens.

Comment: So, after calling close(), if my intention is make the stream object to be eligible for GC, do I need to explicitly set my reference to null?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to nullify stream, once stream is closed and goes out of scope, the stream is marked for Garbage collection automatically.